# How can I mount an iPhone as a drive on OS X

Tags: macos, usb, usb-flash-drive, iphone

When I plug my iPhone in on Windows, it automatically detected as a USB mass-storage device and mounts as a disk.  How can I set this up in Finder under OS X?

Comment: You can use it as a mass-storage device or it just shows as one?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't by default, since iOS in combination with OS X won't allow you to. iOS will only present the iPhone as a camera, so *Image Capture* can pull the pictures stored under `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM`, using the PTP ([Picture Transfer Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol)).

Two options:

- You can jailbreak your iPhone and use the [USB Drive](http://www.ijailbreak.com/applications/cydia-app-make-your-iphone-a-fully-functioning-usb-drive/) app from Cydia to turn the device into an actual USB drive. The "Drive only" mode would allow you to do what you want, if I read your question correctly.
- You could install [PhoneDisk](http://www.macroplant.com/phonedisk/) for OS X, which will monitor any plugged in devices and mount them as drives

  [image]

  Note though that PhoneDisk has been discontinued as of July 2012 and its features have been merged in to [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/).

Comment: Any known issues with iExplorer or is it safe?

Comment: @slhck, in 2021, BigSur, I don't see anything at `/var/mobile/Media/DCIM` when I attached my unlocked iPhone to Image-Capture.app 

Answer (score 24):

There the handy plug-n-play tool *iExplorer* that [slhck mentioned](https://superuser.com/a/465405).. but I am not a fan of paying $35-50+ for a one time use just to mount a filesystem; especially when I already paid a ton of money to buy my Mac. Thanks *iExplorer* for all your work.. but there's a much better solution here.

The *free answer* because god bless the open source (which Apple has made billions on top of already):

- install [homebrew](http://brew.sh) and open a terminal on your Mac to do the rest

After some quick research, *iExplore* is built on top of `osxfuse` and uses common protocols to exchange file information from the device. If you want to see your device, I'd recommend installing `lsusb` to discover the 40-digit uuid (aka serial).

To get `lsusb` working on OSX:

```
brew tap jlhonora/lsusb
brew install lsusb
```

After you type `lsusb` you will see your device listed as:

```
Bus $bus_num Device $dev_num: ID $vendor:$product Apple Inc. iPhone  Serial: $serial
```

Steps to mount the file system **without jailbreaking**:

- `brew tap osxfuse/osxfuse`
- `brew install osxfuse`
- `brew tap Homebrew/homebrew-fuse`
- `brew install ifuse`

Now that `ifuse` is installed you can mount the device like this:

```
cd ~
mkdir ~/iPhone
ifuse ~/iPhone/ -u $serial
```

This will mount the viewable apple filesystem.. but it probably won't give you everything you see in *iExplorer* ..like all the apps and their app data.. well no fear, `ifuse` can do that too. You need one more application to get all the `APPID` (bundle names). That would be `ideviceinstaller`.

```
brew install ideviceinstaller
ideviceinstaller -l
```

The output will be:

```
Total: $number_of apps:
$bundle_name - $bundle_version
..
```

Now if you already mounted the device, I should mention that you first run `sudo umount ~/iPhone` or click the eject link in Finder next to `~/OSXFUSE <whatever>` to unmount that before continuing.

To mount a particular App Container, run:

```
ifuse ~/iPhone/ -u $serial --container $bundle_name
```

You can then either navigate to the folder in Finder or use that good 'ole BSD tool `cp` while you're still in your terminal.

Comment: I can not install `lsusb` - it required password for repository - but you can find uuid from `ioreg -p IOUSB -l -w 0` - field `USB Serial Number`

Comment: $ `ifuse ~/iPad -u 5932dfa1d13b1c5d55327d4278dec08cd3681540`
`Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.
Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device.`

Comment: Same issue as @VitalyZdanevich. This solution no longer works.

Comment: Per https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc#gistcomment-2140745 You can do the following:

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libtool && brew install libtool`, `brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies libimobiledevice && brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice`, and `brew uninstall ifuse && brew install --HEAD ifuse` to get this working.

Comment: I had to be in a root shell for it work!

Comment: @Vitaly Zdanevich The problem seems to be, that macOS expects the iOS to verify that the connection is safe (normally via a popup on the iOS device), but older devices don't support this and therefore the connection seems to be blocked

Comment: Just to confirm that it (still) perfectly works under macOS 10.15 and iOS 13.3. Thank you very much!

Comment: you can do this from a llinux host using: https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc

Comment: Instead of `brew tap homebrew/fuse` it’s now `brew cask install osxfuse`.

Comment: I stucked in `brew tap osxfuse/osxfuse` command. Github says password authentication has been deprecated

Answer (score 2):

Windows does not mount an iPhone as a USB Mass Storage Device.  Just because a device shows up under "My Computer" doesn't means it's a Mass Storage Device.  What Windows is doing is detecting the iPhone as a PTP device, and presenting it there to the user.  The equivalent in Mac OS X is to open a program that imports photos, such as Photos or Preview, and you will see the iPhone listed there.  Mac OS X does not mount PTP devices on the desktop, like it does with USB Mass Storage.

So all the replies on here were how get into the root files of the iPhone, which is not really the equivalent of what the user is seeing on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/samrocketman/70dff6ebb18004fc37dc5e33c259a0fc#gistcomment-2140745

As @mpowered noted in the comments this will work with the last command edited since that will generate the following error `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ifuse`.

```
brew uninstall libtool && brew install libtool
brew uninstall libimobiledevice && brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
brew install --HEAD ifuse
```

Answer (score 0):

PhoneDisk was quite cool, but since Sierra the /Volume folder is no longer writable for everyon, what makes phonedisk fail "Mount failed Unable to Create directory for mount point"
Esasiest way to solve this is to go for it as root in the terminal...
sudo /Applications/PhoneDisk.app/Contents/MacOS/PhoneDisk
Procedure is foolproof: some errors appear, a popup Sytem Extension Blocked will come up, you press the open Security Preferences Button, and allow Benjamin Fleischers Software....
Close all and run again sudo /Applications/PhoneDisk.app/Contents/MacOS/PhoneDisk
The beauty about phonedisk is, that it mounts parts of the iphones/iPads Filesystem on the Mac.
And belod th DCIM (Digital Images) Folder, you find all the photos and films with their time created info.
If copied wit cp -p  , this info will not be lost.